# Add a close icon in a panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a close icon on the right of the title of my panel. But I cannot put it inside the panel:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
      .panel {
      background: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 7px 10px;
      }

      .x_title {
      border-bottom:2px solid #E6E9ED;
      margin-bottom:10px;
      padding:1px 5px 6px;
      font-size:16px;
      }

      .x_title .actions {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      line-height: 3
      }

      .x_title .list-inline {
      margin-left: -13px;
      padding-left: -5px;
      }

      .x_content {
      margin-top:5px;
      padding:0 5px 6px;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="x_title">
      Panel
      <div class="actions list-inline">
        <a href="#" onclick="$('.panel').hide(); $('#br').hide();">&times;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/rihobalivo/2/edit?html,output)

Could anyone help me amend this?

Additionally, I don't know if it is the best way to add a close icon. Bootstrap has `modal`, but it seems that modal is used for **pop-up** window rather than a panel inside a page. Does anyone one know what is the most conventional way to add close icon (and even collapse icon) by Bootstrap and JQuery?

Comment: At the moment, the `x` sign is on the right (and outside) of the panel... I want it to be inside the panel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element with `position: absolute;` will position itself relative to the *page* unless its parent has `position: relative;`.

What you need to change is `.x_title`, like so:

```
.x_title {
    border-bottom:2px solid #E6E9ED;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:1px 5px 6px;
    font-size:16px;
    position: relative;
 }
```

By giving this a `position: relative;`, the `right: 0;` on your `actions` div now refers to the right edge of `x_title`, rather than the right edge of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative;` to your `.panel` class. Then it will stay inside the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative;` to your  `.panel` class.

And `position: absolute; right: 5px; top: 5px;` to `.actions` class

Then it will stay inside the panel right side top corner.